# How to set values for field after executing SQLQuery in Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate-mapping

I have this code

```
query = session.createSQLQuery("select e.emp_id, emp_name, 
    emp_salary,address_line1, city, 
    zipcode from Employee e, Address a where a.emp_id=e.emp_id");
rows = query.list();

for(Object[] row : rows){
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setId(Long.parseLong(row[0].toString()));
    emp.setName(row[1].toString());
    emp.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(row[2].toString()));
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setAddressLine1(row[3].toString());
    address.setCity(row[4].toString());
    address.setZipcode(row[5].toString());
    emp.setAddress(address);
    System.out.println(emp);
}
```

I'm fetching datas from the query and setting it in the for each loop.But I want to set values now like this

```
emp.setName(row[1].toString());
```

I want to fetch data with column names.So that if there are 100 of columns in select statement I have to give `0-99` numbering in the row array. So if say, 46th column I don't want in select query then i have to change the numbering from 46-98. So is there any way to get it done with column names.

**Note: Mapping is done through query not entity/pojo class.**

Comment: You can use `org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata` and `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` to get column names. And then iterating through it set your field values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch data by column names,

```
 query = session.createSQLQuery("select e.emp_id, emp_name, 
  emp_salary,address_line1, city, 
  zipcode from Employee e, Address a where a.emp_id=e.emp_id");
 query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
 List empList= query.list();

 for(Object object : empList) {
    Map row = (Map)object;
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setId(Long.parseLong(row.get("id"));
    emp.setName(row.get("name"));

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias to bean transformer `org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer`.Only those attributes of a Bean will have values , whose alias exists in your database query.

e.g

You `BeanClass.java` is like that

```java
public class Employee{

Integer id;
String name;

// Getter Setters 
}
```

```java
session.createSQLQuery("select e.emp_id as id, emp_name as name");
query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Employee.class));
List<Employee> employeeList = query.list();
```